# create-react-app hangs when initializing an app

Tags: reactjs

It's my first time trying to use it, but after executing:

`create-react-app myproject`

I get:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\project

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

[  ................] \ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule js-tokens@4.0.0
```

And it just hangs there forever.

I'm using `npm 5.6.0` and `create-react-app 2.0.3` on Windows 8.

Comment: since you are install in C drive, perhaps you may try using  cmd with Administrator right

Comment: Didn't work.. i also tried Power Shell. For some reason it's stuck on this `js-tokens@4.0.0`

Comment: do you have the same issue if you try to install from a different location, say myDocuments?

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem, mine got stuck at

```
Creating a new React app in C:\project

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

[  ................] \ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule react-is@4.0.0
```

The solution for me was to ensure npm is up to date by running:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

After this, create-react-app worked correctly.

Comment: This just still worked in 2022. Had a similar problem, even restarted installation a second time. Hanged both times. After installing the latest npm, it didn't hang and finished installing.

Answer (score 5):

If you get stuck while running create-react-app, just <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to end the process in the terminal or CMD.

Then end task "node.exe" from task manager (if you use windows).

Then run in your terminal:

- npm install npm@latest -g
- npm install create-react-app -g
- npx create-react-app (your-project-name)
- cd (your-project-name)
- npm start (inside your code editor, *e.g.* VSCode)

Note: beware of npm vs npx in the commands used above

Answer (score 4):

What I just did is press ctrl + C. My intention is to abort the process, but turns out the process is continue. Still not know any further logical explanation of the 'solution' that I just did, though.

Comment: Apart from not being able to explain, what you mean by solution is unclear, since you describe what seems NOT to help. "I do ... but ..."

Comment: Not just Ctrl+C  but even pressing ENTER key helps !

Answer (score 1):

Re-install Node js 32 bit.

My problem got fixed and same issue was there. Solution is to uninstall Node js and reinstall 32 bit Node js.....Enjoy Thanks

Comment: I have trouble understanding your post. "Re install Node js 32 bit." is unreadable to me. "My problem got fixed." reads like "Thanks.", which would be inappropriate as an answer here. "Same issue was there for me though I installed React js many times, that time no problem were there." is again hard to read, but seems a comment that a proposed solution does not work; at the same time it seems to report some kind of success. "Solution is to uninstall Node js and reinstall 32 bit Node js" is the only hidden part which might actually try to answer appropriately. The rest is fluff. Please [edit].

Comment: @Yunnosch Perhaps we can tolerate a little "fluff" on a first post?

Comment: @RichC I'd tend to agree. But what is your point? (Seeing the edits I now understand that what confused me and got me on the wrong track was 'Re install', which made me think of 'Re: install' and lost me there and then.) I do tolerate fluff and would not flag a post for fluff. But a NAA gets flagged, fluff or not. This I now accept as a fluffy answer, assuming that it is not repeating any of the others. Which I cannot 100% verify, lacking the technical detail knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, what i did is to run the command in nodejs command prompt instead of command prompt. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `npm 5.6.0`, let try using `npx`

Open cmd:

Locate to you `C:\project`

```
C:
cd C:\project
```

Run npx and start the sample project with npm:

```
npx create-react-app myproject
cd myproject
npm start
```

`npx` come out since `npm 5.2`, and just read the document from `create-react-app` [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal/CMD, type resmon and hit enter. Go to overview tab and search for
cmd.exe (for windows users), straight to that, search for suspended. Yes this is the culprit. Right click on that suspended, and click 'resume process' and hit enter.
Click continue if any pop-up occurs :).
That's it you are done. you will see that your installation will continue :).
Repeat the same process if CMD hangs.

Answer (score 0):

adding nodejs path in User Variable worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this; it worked for me:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

then run your command.

Comment: This might forever have your machine stuck at an outdated create-react-app version. The [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start) explicitly advise uninstalling any previously installed instances and using `npx` to make sure the project uses the latest version.