# Creating a new React app fail in Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a new ReactJS project by typing on cmd:

> create-react-app new_project

But the cmd appear like this for hours and no change:

> Creating a new React app in...

My node version: v10.16.3.

My npm version: 6.12.0.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: It might be some little problem. Just stop the execution, Restart the system and try again to create

Comment: I tried to restart the PC but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you can now create a react app by doing this npx create-react-app myapp (if npx not found then first do npm install npx)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

and run again

Similar problem's here

[create-react-app hangs when initializing an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770553/create-react-app-hangs-when-initializing-an-app)

Answer (score 0):

It seems create-react-app not installed globally properly.

Try this

`npm install -g create-react-app`

the **restart** you system.

Now try using the command you used.

`create-react-app new_project`