# npx create-react-app project , it is getting stuck

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

While running the command  `npx create-react-app projectname` , it is getting stuck at this point. I am waiting for it to proceed for hours.

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have network connectivity? Does `npm install react` work?

Comment: Here is thread regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770553/create-react-app-hangs-when-initializing-an-app

Answer (score 0):

First Stage:
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
npm cache clear --force
Delete your package-lock.json file(it will automatically get created after npm i).
Now try for npm install

Second Stage:
In your project directory type
npm init
npm update
Restart your IDE
Try installing dependency again

Third Stage:
Unistall node and npm
Reinstall node again

link: https://dev.to/_ayushcode/fix-npx-create-react-app-stuck-or-hangs-when-installing-or-react-dependencies-getting-stuck-during-npm-install-37dj